# Shell Script issue with comparing file name to string in a loop

Tags: shell, ubuntu, sh, cat, rm

Here is the issue. I have a directory with over 100,000K files on an Ubuntu 14.04 Server. I need to process the files in the background so I wrote a shell script the cats the files to a larger one and then removes the file. However the issue that comes into play is that is also cats the process script and the output file. Any ideas?

```
#!/bin/sh
c=0
#loop through 1000 results at 1 time
d=1000 

  while [ $c -lt $d ]
    do
      filename=$(`ls | head -n 1`)
      #echo $filename

  if [ $filename == "process.sh" ]
    then
    break
  fi

  if [ $filename ==  "file.txt" ]
    then
    break
  fi

  cat `ls | head -n 1` >> file.txt
  rm `ls | head -n 1`
  #echo $c
  c=`expr $c + 1`

done
```

Comment: You could remove the offending lines after your processing is done: `sed -i.bak '/pattern to match/d' ./file.txt`

Comment: The issue is that the files that are being processed the number is not fixed. There are always files added in batches. By this I mean sometimes there are 100,000 and sometimes less. I guess I could get a count of files at first and -1 from the loop since the other files all have numerical names. Not sure, I need to brush on my knowledge of shell script I guess.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, `ls | head -n 1` will always return the first file. I don't see this script progressing through files. Also shouldn't the line `filename=$(`ls | head -n 1`)` be `filename=$(ls | head -n 1)`? When doing simple math I prefer the format `c=$((c+1))`.

Comment: Don't call `ls` at all in the loop.  If you want to work on the first 1000 files (and you want to be parsing `ls` at all), just do something like `ls | sed 1000q | while read filename; do ...`

Comment: Also, put your script and output file in a different directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call `ls | head -n 1` only once in each loop. After the checks you call `ls | head -n 1` again and the result can be different (a concurrent process.sh still running or new files).
How do you want to get files listed after `file.txt` ? You are breaking out of the loop, other files will be skipped. Do not change this in continue, because than you will keep assigning `file.txt` to `filename`.
Always use double quotes for your vars (think about `my file.txt`), and you might want to get used to braces as well.

Suppose your batch works fine and it has processed the last not-special file. `"${filename}"` will be empty! So start with testing `if [ -f "${filename}" ]`, that will solve the problems with directories as well.

I really hope you have permission for removing those files, so you won't get stuck processing the same file 1000 times.

You shouldn't process `ls` output, so the alternative

```
ls | egrep -v "file.txt|process.sh" | head -n 1
```

is only a different way doing it wrong.

When you get a `"${filename}"` and want to check this against a number of strings, you might want to use `case "${filename}" in ... esac`.

When your files don't have newlines, you can use a `find` with `xargs`.

```
# First test it
find . -type f \( ! -name process.sh -a ! -name file.txt \) 2>/dev/null |
   head -10 | xargs -I % sh -c 'echo "File %"; echo "rm -f %"'
# Looking nice?
find . -type f \( ! -name process.sh -a ! -name file.txt \) 2>/dev/null |
   head -1000 | xargs -I % sh -c 'cat "%" > file.txt; rm -f "%"'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite the script.

```
#!/bin/bash

c=0
d=1000

for file in $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f \( ! -name process.sh -a ! -name file.txt \))
do
    cat $file >> file.txt
    rm $file
    c=$((c+1))
    if [ $c -eq $d ]; then
        break
    fi
done
```